# How to rewrite a csv for QGIS to avoid "Invalid record format"?

Tags: qgis, python, csv

So, 
I have a .csv file.

Here an example how the a row from the original .csv looks like:

```
"AREA",44.37,-00.83,"5","1","8","E","E",,,"KKI","KKO"
```

Some lines have missing latitudes and longitudes, so I want to get rid of them.
Should be easy. Thats my snippet (Python 2.7) that does it:

```
import csv

n = 0
m = 0

nf = open("newfilefile.csv", "w")

with open("oldfile.csv", "r") as csvFile:
    originalData = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=",")
    for lines in originalData:

        if len(lines[9]) < 1:
            n += 1
            print 'Missing Latitude', n

        elif len(lines[10]) < 1:
            m += 1
            print 'Missing Longitude', m

        else:
             nf.write(str(lines[0]).strip() + "," + str(lines[1]).strip() + "," + str(lines[2]).strip()  + "," + str(lines[3]).strip() + "," + str(lines[4]).strip() + "," + str(lines[5]).strip() ...  + "\n" )

nf.close()
```

Thats how the same row would look like in my new .csv:

```
AREA,44.37,-00.83,5,1,8,E,E,,,KKI,KKO
```

Beforehand I could open the original csv file. QGis just said that there are missing geometry information. Now I get a bunch of errors, namely: 
`Invalid record format at line 324`
and so forth... I compared the lines where it marks the error and the only difference is that in the oldfile, everything is wrapped in `"` while in the file my script creates that is not the case.

Why does QGis need `"` around every from a column (if that is the mistake) and how would I add that to my snippet?

Comment: Not everything is wrapped with `"` but only columns which contain strings. `"5"` is a string but `5`is a number -> schema mismatch -> failure.

Comment: @user30184 Alright. I understand. Thanks!

Comment: @user30184 What I still do not understand is why my columns do not get wrapped with `"` since I convert everything into a string...

Comment: There is no general standard that strings should be surrounded by double quotes. You must code it yourself: if string then put it between double quotes else just write. Read also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308097/writing-double-quotes-in-python.

Comment: @user30184 Ah i thought there is a general standard! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the best solution to read, work on and write csv files is the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) module.

Read a csv file (an example)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
print df 
   type   long   lat   o   x   y   z   t
0  AREA  44.37 -0.83   5   1 NaN NaN   KKO
1  AREA    NaN   NaN   5   1   8   3   KKO
2  AREA  46.48 -0.85 NaN NaN NaN NaN   KKO
3  AREA  46.52   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   KKO
4  AREA    NaN -0.75 NaN NaN NaN NaN   KKO
```

Eliminate all the rows with no longitude or with no latitude or with no longitude and no latitude

```
nolong = df.dropna(subset=['long'])
print nolong
   type   long   lat   o   x   y   z    t
0  AREA  44.37 -0.83   5   1 NaN NaN   KKO
2  AREA  46.48 -0.85 NaN NaN NaN NaN   KKO
3  AREA  46.52   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   KKO
nolat = df.dropna(subset=['lat'])
print nolat
   type   long   lat   o   x   y   z    t
0  AREA  44.37 -0.83   5   1 NaN NaN   KKO
2  AREA  46.48 -0.85 NaN NaN NaN NaN   KKO
4  AREA    NaN -0.75 NaN NaN NaN NaN   KKO
nolonglat = df.dropna(subset=['long','lat'])
print nolonglat
   type   long   lat   o   x   y   z prout
0  AREA  44.37 -0.83   5   1 NaN NaN   KKO
2  AREA  46.48 -0.85 NaN NaN NaN NaN   KKO
```

Save the resulting csv file (you can also use the [geopandas](http://geopandas.org/) module to create directly a shapefile, [Using the python shape library: pyshp - how to convert polygons in .csv file to .shp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70786/using-the-python-shape-library-pyshp-how-to-convert-polygons-in-csv-file-to/70883#70883))

```
nolonglat.to_csv('test2.csv', sep=',', index = False)
```

Import in QGIS

[image]

If you want to use the csv module, use the [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) classes

```
import csv
with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile):
        if row['long'] and row['lat']:
            print row
 {'t': 'KKO', 'o': '5', 'y': '', 'long': '44.37', 'lat': '-00.83', 'x': '1', 'z': '', 'type': 'AREA'}
 {'t': 'KKO', 'o': '', 'y': '', 'long': '46.48', 'lat': '-00.85', 'x': '', 'z': '', 'type': 'AREA'}
```

Then you can use the [DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) class to write the csv file or the [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) module to create directly a shapefile ([Using Fiona to write a new shapefile from scratch](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97545/using-fiona-to-write-a-new-shapefile-from-scratch/97563#97563))

Comment: thanks. I will look into the pandas module. looks promising!