# Is it possible to use non-printable characters as delimiter for text file layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, csv, ascii, delimiter

I am trying to import a Delimited Text File Layer from a .csv file in QGIS. Because this caused a lot of errors, I posted a question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/150402/understand-qgis-errors-when-importing-csv-file) and got the hint towards using ASCII non-printable control characters as delimiters. These are described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#ASCII_delimited_text) and in this [blog post](https://ronaldduncan.wordpress.com/2009/10/31/text-file-formats-ascii-delimited-text-not-csv-or-tab-delimited-text/).

Since I am using Tweets, for which it is very difficult to find a convenient delimiter because nearly all characters are used in them, I really want to give this a shot. However, I cannot find out how to import a text file into QGIS specifying these characters as delimiters. I tried the different spellings that are given in Wikipedia as custom characters and as regular expression.

```
0x31
0x1F
^_
```

None of these work. Interestingly, the lines are detected correctly - only the record delimiters are a problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Have you thought about using a combination delimiter?  For instance, if you know *$*, *^*, and *#* may be used in your string, make the delimiter *#&^*.  I am not sure if QGIS supports multiple character delimiters directly.  You can always call python's `split("#&^")` in order to manually split the string and handle individual values that way.

We ran into that issue and ended up using *¬* as a delimiter because we knew that would never be collected in a shapefile.  We keep the same standing encoding but used an alt-key character.

Comment: I did exactly that, but there were a lot of import errors and I got the hint that maybe this was a problem. Although, QGIS seems to support this, but sometimes using multiple delimiters does not work, so I thought I'd rather not get used to it.

Comment: Some of the problems we ran in to using an alt-key character was that sometimes certain GIS programs would interpret it wrong and mess up the encoding.  Basically, using *¬* has led to issues trying to utilize the `OLEDB` driver in .NET to access the DBF because the encoding gets all screwy.  I couldn't figure a way around it, but I am sure I just didn't adjust to the proper encoding for reading in the DBF to it.