# Convert multiple CSV files to shapefiles using Python?

Tags: python, shapefile, csv

At my internship, I have been asked to learn Python on the job.  It's been a rough road never having coded before so please forgive me if my problem is elementary.

The Lightning CSV files I am trying to convert have over 400,000 rows.
The headers go as follows:  `mon, day, year, hr, min, sec, lat, lon, ht, type, Ip, Id`

I found the answers to this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/using-the-python-shape-library-pyshp-how-to-convert-csv-file-to-shp?lq=1) as potential solutions. I struggle to modify this code in order to convert the CSVs into shapefiles.

The path for the CSVs is C:\Users\zherran\Desktop\shp\enwest2015*.csv

The path where I want the shapefile C:\Users\zherran\Desktop\shp\shapefiles

```
import shapefile as shp
import csv

out_file = 'enwest3days.shp'

#Set up blank lists for data
mon,day,year,hr,min,sec,lat,lon,ht,type,Ip,Id=[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]

# sample row mon,day,year,hr,min,sec,lat,lon,ht,type,Ip,Id
#            6,2,2015,7,27,16.6,41.5,-101.4,13789.5,1,-7900,26abb8a


#read data from csv file and store in lists
with open('enwest*.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    r = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for i,row in enumerate(r):
        if i > 0: #skip header
            mon.append(int(row[0]))
            day.append(int(row[1]))
            year.append(int(row[2]))
            hr.append(int(row[3]))
            min.append(int(row[4]))
            sec.append(float(row[5]))
            lat.append(float(row[6]))
            lon.append(float(row[7]))
            ht.append(float(row[8]))
            type.append(int(row[9]))
            Ip.append(float(row[10]))
            Id.append(complex(row[11]))

#Set up shapefile writer and create empty fields
w = shp.Writer(shp.POINT)
w.autoBalance = 1 #ensures gemoetry and attributes match
w.field('X','F',10,8)
w.field('Y','F',10,8)
w.field('Date','D')
w.field('Target','C',50)
w.field('ID','N')
w.field('ID','N')
w.field('ID','N')
w.field('ID','N')
w.field('ID','N')
w.field('ID','N')
w.field('ID','N')

#loop through the data and write the shapefile
for j,k in enumerate(x):
    w.point(k,y[j]) #write the geometry
    w.record(k,y[j],date[j], target[j], id_no[j]) #write the attributes

#Save shapefile
w.save(out_file)
```

Comment: You should add the code that you have written.

Comment: The reason I ask to see your code is that it sounds as if you are having difficulty with Python syntax and programming concepts generally: with just the posted code from someone else, we have no idea what *you* don't understand.

Comment: Do you have to use python? If this is just a task you need to get done you could try using GDAL/OGR commandline libraries. Specifically the ogr2ogr function, this post is extremely useful for what you've got: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127518/convert-csv-to-kml-or-geojson-etc-using-ogr2ogr-or-equivalent-command-line-tool. If you are set on using Python, I would also recommend using the GDAL/OGR python modules.

Comment: As @Dave-Evans said, do you have your heart set on 'shapefile'? OGR is available for python and has a driver for CSV which would simplify all this code down to a few lines.

Comment: can you explain what is actually not working?

Comment: @iant thank you for the edits! I just back to the office this morning and I am wrapping up the process of changing the variables in order to give the specifics.

Comment: @Dave-Evans thank you for the suggestion!  I will look into using the GDAL/OGR modules.  I'll post an update when I get the chance to work with!

Comment: @RichardLaw  so after modifying the code (as seen above), what I am having difficulty understanding is how the pyshp datatype letters and corresponding numbers signify in the w.field portion of the code.

Comment: FYI, I'm using Spyder (Python 3.5)

Answer (score 3):

a) With the solution you use ([Pyshp (shapefile](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp)), you need

1) to extract the fields of the csv file
2) to define the fields of the shapefile (`w.field('Target','C',50)`)
3) to construct the geometry from the lon et lat fields ( `w.point(float(i['x']),float(i['y'])`) (see [CSV to Shapefile](http://geospatialpython.com/2015/08/csv-to-shapefile.html) )

b) With [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html), it is easier but you have the same problem of field definition.
c) [osgeo/ogr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/) complicates the things...
d) Therefore, be modern, to convert directly csv files to shapefiles, the best solution is now [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), [GeoPandas](http://geopandas.org/)(uses [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html))  and [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html). You do not have to worry about the fields  and the fields definitions ([pandas.DataFrame.from_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html)).

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame
from shapely.geometry import Point
# convert the csv file to a DataFrame
data = DataFrame.from_csv('enwest2015_1.csv', index_col=False)
# extract the geometry from the DataFrame
points = [Point(row['lon'], row['lat']) for key, row in data.iterrows()]
#convert the DataFrame to a GeoDataFrame 
geo_df = GeoDataFrame(data,geometry=points)
# save the resulting shapefile
geo_df.to_file('enwest2015_1.shp', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

For the paths, it is a pure Python problem

Comment: `from_csv` is deprecated. Use `pandas.read_csv()`